# Is there a Service Fabric notification BEFORE it takes down a service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I have setup a service that uses `RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync` to get notified of service change events.  It works as intended.  When a service goes down, this event gets called.

But it happens AFTER the service has gone offline.  Which means that several requests could have failed against that now offline service before I get it pulled out of my loadbalancer pool.

Sometimes Service Fabric can only react to a service going offline.  For example, if someone pulls the plug on a server node, Service Fabric clearly can't tell me in advance that the service is going offline.

But many times, a threshold is reached and it is Service Fabric itself that kills the service (and starts a new one).

**Is there a way to know BEFORE Service Fabric kills a service?**  (So I have time to update my loadblancer.)

(In case it matters, I am running Service Fabric on premises.)

Comment: You should have a retry logic when your clients are calling your service. SF can redirect your call to another instance for various reasons. Maybe this is the place where you can catch these downtimes and act accordingly; you can push these events to another queue to be processed there.

Comment: @Robert - my apps "should" have that.  But many don't.  There will be plenty of issues with moving to Service Fabric that I don't need to add failures to it just because Service Fabric migrating a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can only be notified on shutdown inside the service. RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync is based on endpoint changes from the naming service.

If it's a reliable service, you get events for these scenarios: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle

For guest executeables the signal Service Fabric send is Ctrl+C. For containers it's "docker stop".